# Can you do conditional text in Confluence

Tags: confluence

I need to do a Confluence page that describes the usage of an app.   The instructions are slightly different for Mac, Linux and Windows users.   Rather than create and maintain three separate pages, I'm wondering if it's possible in Confluence to have the user somehow select what OS they're using, and then simply swap out an image or a paragraph depending on what they chose?

Comment: I think this should be quite easy to do by creating your own macro: https://tmcalm.nl/blog/confluence-user-macros-an-introduction/ I'm not sure of any other ways